# How to remove a specific word from a file in perl

Tags: perl, unix

A file contains:

```
    rhost=localhost
    ruserid=abcdefg_xxx
    ldir=
    lfile=
    rdir=p01
    rfile=
    pgp=none
    mainframe=no
    ftpmode=binary
    ftpcmd1=
    ftpcmd2=
    ftpcmd3=
    ftpcmd1a=
    ftpcmd2a=
    notifycc=no
    firstfwd=Yes
    NOTIFYNYL=
    decompress=no
    compress=no
```

I want to write a simple code that removes the "_xxx" in that second line. Keep in mind that there will never be a file that contains the string "_xxx" so that should make it extremely easier. I'm just not too familiar with the syntax. Thanks!

Comment: `Keep in mind`, hmmm, yes I will keep that in mind as I do your job for you. I asked nicely on a previous post, now I will just ask: please show us the code you are working on, otherwise it seems that you are asking us to do your job for you. This is a help site, not a free contracting site. http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The short answer:**

Here's how you can remove just the literal '`_xxx`'.

`perl -pli.bak -e 's/_xxx$//' filename`

**The detailed explanation:**

Since Perl has a reputation for code that is indistinguishable from line noise, here's an explanation of the steps.

`-p` creates an implicit loop that looks something like this:

```
while( <> ) {
    # Your code goes here.
}
continue {
    print or die;
}
```

`-l` sort of acts like "auto-chomp", but also places the line ending back on the line before printing it again.  It's more complicated than that, but in its simplest use, it changes your implicit loop to look like this:

```
while( <> ) {
    chomp;
    # Your code goes here.
}
continue {
    print $_, $/;
}
```

-i tells Perl to "edit in place."  Behind the scenes it creates a separate output file and at the end it moves that temporary file to replace the original.

`.bak` tells Perl that it should create a backup named 'originalfile.**bak**' so that if you make a mistake it can be reversed easily enough.

Inside the substitution:

```
s/
    _xxx$     # Match (but don't capture) the final '_xxx' in the string.
 /$1/x;       # Replace the entire match with nothing.
```

**The reference material:**

For future reference, information on the command line switches used in Perl "one-liners" can be obtained in Perl's documentation at [perlrun](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html).  A quick introduction to Perl's regular expressions can be found at [perlrequick](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrequick.html).  And a quick overview of Perl's syntax is found at [perlintro](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlintro.html).

Answer (score 1):

This overwrites the original file, getting rid of `_xxx` in the 2nd line:

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use Tie::File;

my $filename = shift;
tie my @lines, 'Tie::File', $filename or die $!;
$lines[1] =~ s/_xxx//;
untie @lines;
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this can help

```
perl -ple 's/_.*// if /^ruserid/' < file
```

will remove anything after the 1st '_' (included) in the line what start with "ruserid".

Comment: so when I execute that i replaced file with $ARGV[0] and then i typed in the filename i want to edit. all it does is print it out, and the file is never changed...

Comment: the above works as filter = read from STDIN and write to STDOUT. It's how to designed the answer and how -l[np]e works.

Answer (score 0):

One way using `perl`. In second line (`$. == 2`), delete from last `_` until end of line:

```
perl -lpe 's/_[^_]*\Z// if $. == 2' infile
```